# change app language as device language change

Tags: android, localization

I am new to localization.

I want to change my app language as device language change...for ex. if device language set to Hindi my app also should change like facebook....

for this what should I do? create string.xml for all possibilities? or is there any library? I am asking for simplification if any...

well I know this code is used to set local

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt_PT");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

but I can't understand how to meet all language support.

Comment: Create different `values` folder for `string.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a directory called `values-<desired-locale>` at the same level with default `values` directory. Examples: `values-de for` German, `values-es` for Spanish.
2. Create a `strings.xml` file inside that directory and populate it with translations of your texts inside default `strings.xml`.
3. Voila! System will use correct `strings.xml` depending on the device locale.

Comment: i know it can be achived by creating values....but i want to support all possible language...to meet n device requirement..what should i do....is there any easy way?

Comment: @HRaval you want to support all languages? Well, you need to first *know* all languages. The OS won't translate it for you :)

Comment: i just asking for any easy way if any....i know OS people are not here to do my work....i want my app to react on language change like fb

Comment: @HRaval You can create as many resource directories as you wish and supply as many translations. I guess this is exactly what the FB app does, they just bundle a lot of translations into the app. I haven't heard of a solution to translate texts automatically based on device locale, and even if there was one - the translation quality would probably not be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

just create values folder like below

```
 1  Afrikanns
Code: af. Folder name: values-af


2   Arabic
Code: ar. Folder name: values-ar

3   Bengali
Code: bn. Folder name: values-bn

4   Czech
Code: cs. Folder name: values-cs

5   Chinese
Code: zh. Folder name: values-zh

6   German
Code: de. Folder name: values-de

7   French
Code: fr. Folder name: values-fr

8   Japanese
Code: ja. Folder name: values-ja
```

Add all string values that your app needs.sysytem will change language automatically when phone language is changed.